# LevelListDrawable without maxLevel

Tags: android, imageview

I have two images - image1 and image2. I want to display either of them based on a particular count using 'LevelListDrawable'.

If the count = 0, display image1, if the count > 0 (can be any value), display image2.

I created following drawable xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />
    <item android:minLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/image2" />
</level-list>
```

in layout xml,

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/level"/>
```

and in code,

```
myImageView.setImageLevel(count);
```

Its working fine when count = 0. But not working when count is non-zero.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As [developer.android.com says](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable) you should use `android:maxLevel` attribute for all your items, but you are using `android:minLevel` attribute for a second item.
Try to refactor your code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />
    <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/image2" />
</level-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Oleh Sokolov! I cannot set 'android:maxLevel' for the second item, as there is no maximum value for the count

Comment: @coder visit a link to developer.android.com there's a code example with android:maxLevel attribute set for all items, so I think you can, but actually I didn't try by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I used '10000' as the `android:maxLevel` for the second item, where 10000 is the maximum value that can be set for `android:maxLevel` according to [Drawable.setLevel(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#setLevel(int))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />
    <item android:maxLevel="10000" android:drawable="@drawable/image2" />
</level-list>
```